# Using JS to create user-customized home pages

Tags: javascript, file

I believe this question is related to this one also, since I'm trying to figure out different aspects of creating a custom homepage: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547110/is-it-possible-to-control-programs-with-javascript)

Once again, I'm developing a downloadable homepage (a custom index.html file + some images and more if needed) that you can store on your computer and then set it as your homepage. It would have a compact layout where you could sort your favorite bookmarks and other stuff the way you want. So the idea is clear.
In the previous question (link above) I wondered whether it's possible to write/read from a file with JS. Unfortunately, it isn't and I do not want to utilize any plugins or an ActiveX object.

I would like to know whether it is possible to add new lines of code (user input) to the page file? For instance, if index.html is the file from which the script is running, can the same script add new lines of code to it? Not an external file, but to the same file the script is running on at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing to a file, I recommend using `localStorage`. It's a persistent JavaScript object that is stored across pageviews and sessions.

```
alert(localStorage.myStorageKey);
localStorage.myStorageKey = 'test';
```

Try [using the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/TyRUV/) and refreshing the page.

Comment: How much data can it store? Does it work in all modern browsers? And where does it actually store that data?

Comment: IE 8, Chrome 4, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10.50, Safari 4. You can usually store up to 5 MB (more for `file://` URLs). It's stored in the user profile of the browser. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage

Comment: Is this actually an HTML5 object? In other words, is the following link the correct resource of information: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I wouldn't ever use w3schools.com as a resource of information, but yes, that is the one.

Comment: Well, I'm obviously a beginner at this and that website seems valuable, at least for now, while I'm still learning the very basics. Why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: I prefer a somewhat more mature documentation. [Mozilla usually provides very good documentation on JavaScript features - after all, they are the ones who built JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)

Comment: Ahh, that's where I've been learning about the <canvas> element of HTML5. w3schools is a good resource for a beginner like me; it's good enough for understanding the basics. I already feel that w3schools is a tutorial site for absolute beginners and that later I'll have to look for other resources.